# Pass wordpress variables in post to jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jQuery function where I take 10 images and load each one by clicking a colour on a colour picker chart.

[jsfiddle here coutesy of TNCodeMonkey](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/M9ysa/3/)

I need to integrate this so it appears in selected Wordpress posts. I am correctly enqueing and loading the latest version of jQuery in my functions.php file.

I'd like to list these images within the post as shortcodes like so:

```
[picker1img]/images/image1.jpg[/picker1img]
[picker2img]/images/image1.jpg[/picker2img]
[picker3img]/images/image1.jpg[/picker3img]
etc
```

then filter the post so that my jQuery script has these image paths passed to it.

Updated note: There are other images in the post but I only want to pass those in the shortcodes. I am not tied to any particlular shortcode syntax.

I need to know the best way to hook into the post and get these image variables out then display my code within the post loop.

I also need to know if I can load this as a plugin rather than in functions.php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious about a few things. Are these images already attached to the posts in question?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [Register the shortcodes](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/), and wrap the images in something simple, like `<div class="post-images"></div>`. Then using `$('.post-images img')` you can retrieve them. I won't provide the actual code, as that would be doing your work for you. Give it a try and if you have problems, come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Is it ok if you use just `[pickerimg]/image1.jpg[/pickerimg][pickerimg]/image2.jpg[/pickerimg]`? It would be relatively easy to create a `[pickerimg]` shortcode, which would also hook to `wp_footer` and print a script there. The script will contain all recorded images in an array for example

Comment: @Nikola Ivanov Nikolov Why hook into the wp_footer? This should be a filter for the posts with conditional statements built into to filter the query when necessary. `function conditionalPostHook($posts, $query){ //conditional logic to grab image paths .. return something } add_filter('the_posts', 'conditionalPostHook');`

Comment: Well there are many ways to accomplish that. Hooking to `wp_footer` would be so that we output something like `<script>images = ['/image1.jpg','/image2.jpg']</script>`. You can then access your variable from JS. The idea is that we use the shortcode API(which will do the parsing for you) and we make a JS variable, because I think it will be faster to access a JS variable vs. looping over a jQuery object(as @ChristianVarga suggested).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No the post contains other images but not the ones I pass with the shotcode. I should have mentioned this as the code from Christian Varga won't work here as it stands. The WP installation has 1400 posts of which about 20 will use this code so any speed increase is valued.

Comment: Listen. I need to know the conditions under which to show these images. As @Christian Varga said, adding shortcodes is the simple part. What we need to do is to identify under what circumstances the shortcode should run and process images. That's what we're lacking here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy OK. When I have a post that I want to show colour options for my product, I want to load the Jquery color picker and 10 images, each in a different color, selectable by clicking the color picker. For a post that has no colour options I don't want to invoke the color picker code.

Comment: Is this code only for products? Or...I mean, you gave a good example, but what i need to know is how do we differentiate between the posts have the code and what doesn't. Are we doing it based on the post type, the post category, the post id, the post name...how are we going to do the conditional statement?

Comment: If it needs it, I can put each post to have the color picker in a separate category or setup a custom post variable. For me, that's the easy part. Are you saying that I should do 'If category=colorpicker run jQuery function'? Can't I just do 'If our shortcode exists run jQuery function'?

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on the best way to go forward here please? I'm still open to suggestions and would like to incorporate this in a plugin if possible.